# Relation of appcompat_v7_4 with armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, native, android-appcompat

When i add appcompat_v7_4 as an library project to my android project, my app tries to find native libs in armeabi-v7a folder, but i only have armeabi folder. And then app crashes because cant find the native libs. I created armeabi-v7a folder and copied armeabi folder content to armeabi-v7a folder and app worked without crash. What is the relation of appcompat_v7_4 with armeabi-v7a?

The stack trace is the following:

```java
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:76)
at com.butterfly.recorder.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:231)
at com.butterfly.RecordActivity.createRecorder(RecordActivity.java:329)
at com.butterfly.RecordActivity.initRecorder(RecordActivity.java:314)
at com.butterfly.RecordActivity.onClick(RecordActivity.java:518)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniavcodec from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.butterfly-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.butterfly-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:86)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avcodec from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.butterfly-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.butterfly-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
... 21 more
```

Comment: AppCompat does not have NDK binaries. How have you determined that your "app tries to find native libraries in armeabi-v7a"?

Comment: @CommonsWare i updated my question and gave detail.

Comment: "And then app crashes because cant find the native libs" -- please post the stack trace. "What is the relation of appcompat_v7_4 with armeabi-v7a? " -- there should not be one.

Comment: java code runs on virtual machine in order to relieve us from cpu and os architectures so I dont think cpu architecture like arm or atom has anything to do with your app crashing.

Comment: @IllegalArgument: No, it is entirely possible that there are NDK-related problems here, as the NDK does result in CPU architecture-specific code. It's just that AppCompat should not have any impact on whether those problems appear.

Comment: @CommonsWare i added stack trace.

Comment: I suspect that you have some other problem, one that is merely being uncovered as a side effect of adding AppCompat to the project.